# getting data out of a closure that retrieves data from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, closures, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from Firebase and store that data outside of the closure that retrieves that data.

```
    var stringNames = [String] ()
    ref?.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        var newNames: [String] = []
        for item in snapshot.children {
            if let item = item as? FIRDataSnapshot {
                let postDict = item.value as! [String: String]
                newNames.append(postDict["name"]!)
            }
        }
        stringNames = newNames
    })
    print(stringNames)
```

stringNames comes back empty, but when I print from inside the closure it has the correct data. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because when you fetch data from Firebase the call is Asynchronous. What you can do:

Option 1 - Set your logic inside the closure (Like what you have that print the var inside the closure).

Option 2 - Define your own closure that going to receive your data like:

```
func myMethod(success:([String])->Void){

    ref?.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        var newNames: [String] = []
        for item in snapshot.children {
            if let item = item as? FIRDataSnapshot {
                let postDict = item.value as! [String: String]
                newNames.append(postDict["name"]!)
            }
        }
        success(newNames)
    })
}
```

Option 3 - Use the delegate pattern

```
protocol MyDelegate{
     func didFetchData(data:[String])
}

class MyController : UIViewController, MyDelegate{

    func myMethod(success:([String])->Void){
        ref?.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
           var newNames: [String] = []
           for item in snapshot.children {
               if let item = item as? FIRDataSnapshot {
                   let postDict = item.value as! [String: String]
                   newNames.append(postDict["name"]!)
               }
            }
            self.didFetchData(newNames)
        })
    }

    func didFetchData(data:[String]){
        //Do what you want
    }

}
```

Comment: The delegate pattern worked really nicely for what I wanted to do with the data, thank you!