# How do you display 2 tableViews of the same user? Firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

Firebase Database

[image: Firebase Database]

driver1 Main page

[image: driver1 Main page]

toyota car details

[image: toyota car details]

FInal Output

[image]
So the problem is that driver1 has 2 cars. how can i make the tableView show for toyota car information and mazda car information.

I was able to show driver 1's car list by this code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "driverRequestCell", for: indexPath)

if let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email {

Database.database().reference().child("Driver").queryOrdered(byChild: "email").queryEqual(toValue: email).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

    let snapshot = self.driverRequests[indexPath.row]

    if let driverRequestDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {

    if let typeOfCar = driverRequestDictionary["car"] as? String {

            cell.textLabel?.text = typeOfCar

        }
    }
})
}
return cell

}
```

So my current code for didSelectRowAt is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let snapshot = driverRequests[indexPath.row]

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "carDetailsSegue", sender: snapshot)

}
```

I think it has something to do with the snapshot, but I can't figure it out. Need help from the pro's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show all car information in the same cell, first you need a cell with three UILabel, one for all of the information you want to show, This is an example:

[image]

I suppose you have your own custom cell class, so you need to drag&drop label outlets into your class.

Now, you have to change you code into cellForRowAt: this way:

```
if let driverRequestDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {

if let typeOfCar = driverRequestDictionary["car"] as? String {
        cell.modelLabel?.text = typeOfCar
    }

if let colorOfCar = driverRequestDictionary["color"] as? String {
        cell.colorLabel?.text = colorOfCar
    }

if let plateOfCar = driverRequestDictionary["plate"] as? String {
        cell.plateLabel?.text = plateOfCar
    }
}
```

You can use a default value if color and plate doesn't exists adding else statements, or using three operand:

```
`if let plateOfCar = driverRequestDictionary["plate"] as? String {
        cell.plateLabel?.text = plateOfCar
    }else{
       cell.plateLabel?.text = "Unknown"
    }`
```

> ***ADVICE:*** Avoid to do a request into cellForRowAt:, Instead of this, make an asynchronous request (on viewDidLoad: for example) using a closure. Then use the result of the closure to fill an array and then reload you table view.

***EDIT:***

You should struct your nodes this way,  where giuseppesapienza is user ID, while note is your car objext:

[image]

Comment: hello Andrea, thanks for replying. the information shows but when i tap on the mazda car, the information for toyota still show. its like whenever driver1@gmail.com adds a car, the recent information shows even when the other cars are selected

Comment: im still using the code you wrote, i have a list of problems and you've answered one of them. thanks!

Comment: Hi Nick, please to hear this, but I don't understand, Do you actually have problems or are they all resolved ?

Comment: the problem is that when i press toyota or mazda, the information for toyota shows.

Comment: I'v added another photo so that it would be easier to understand.

Comment: Actually, the model definition is wrong. You have two users with different ID but they're actually the same user. You need another type of structure, I will show you a pic

Comment: I really appreciate you spending time for this, thank you so much. so youre saying that i should structure it by "car" not by "user"?

Comment: I got this structure from an online UBER app clone tutorial and i want it to do more. Like the driver can register 2 or more cars.

Comment: I say so because is not maintenable with lot of users and cars. However can you show driverRequests?  Why do you declare snapshot if the callback already give one to you?

Comment: driverRequests is just "var driverRequests : [DataSnapshot] = []" im kinda used in using that "Database.database().reference().child..."  in retrieving data from database

Comment: Remove let snapshot = self.driverRequests[indexPath.row] and try to print out snapshot.value, what you get ?

Comment: If i remove let snapshot = self.driverRequests[indexPath.row] I get the car lists of driver1 with the information in the debug area. In the simulator, My Cars page, its just Mazda Mazda

Comment: well, this is the behaviour you need, but when you do 
    if let typeOfCar = driverRequestDictionary["car"] as? String, you need to do this for all the car on the dictionary

Comment: is there a way that i can retrieve the childByAutoID created by driver1 so at least can gather the information

Comment: Yes, for sure. check here at https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39328328/firebase-retrieve-childbyautoid-from-realtime-database%3Frq%3D1&ved=2ahUKEwi2tL3qpNvdAhWOM-wKHf88BykQjjgwAXoECAgQAQ&usg=AOvVaw177e31bLQquN-vjhwiHJvE

Comment: thanks @Andrea Abbate, I've manage to figure out some stuff with your help.

Comment: Hi @Andrea, is there a way that i can make the value of snapshot global, so that I can use them in UILabels?

Comment: Actually, I think it's a better way to access the UILabel into snapshot closure, but if you mean the UILabel of the cell, you need to store the snapshot value into an external variable.
For example you put a class variable MyClass{ var actualSnapshot; viewDidLoad(){} ecc.. }, then when you get the snapshot you can do self.actualSnapshot = snapshot.
If you want to do something after setting actual snapshot you can use this notation:   var actualSnapshot: Type = Type(){ didSet{ self.collectionView.reloadData()} } for example

Comment: is it similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45426984/how-to-pass-data-out-of-a-closure-that-retrieves-info-from-firebase